# Append output function to multiple lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, append

I want to execute a function with different parameter values. I have the following snippet of code which works perfectly well:

```
tau = np.arange(2,4.01,0.1)
R = []
P = []
T = []
L = []
D = []
E = []
Obj = []
for i, tenum in enumerate(tau):
    [r, p, t, l, d, e, obj] = (foo.cvxEDA(edaN, 1./fs, tenum, 0.7, 10.0, 0.0008, 0.01))
    R.append(r)
    P.append(p)
    T.append(t)
    L.append(l)
    D.append(d)
    E.append(e)
    Obj.append(obj)
```

However, I was wondering though: **Is there an easier way to accomplish this?**

---

I have tried using 
`res.append(foo.cvxEDA(edaN, 1./fs, tenum, 0.7, 10.0, 0.0008, 0.01)` but `res[1]` returns `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x046E7698>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn a generator object into a list object by just passing it to the `list()` function so maybe this will do what you want:

```
res = []
for i, tenum in enumerate(tau):
   res.append(list(foo.cvxEDA(edaN, 1./fs, tenum, 0.7, 10.0, 0.0008, 0.01)))
```

Even shorter with a list comprehension:

```
res = [list(foo.cvxEDA(edaN, 1./fs, tenum, 0.7, 10.0, 0.0008, 0.01)) for i, tenum in enumerate(tau)]
```

Either way, this leaves res transposed compared to what you want (thinking of it as a matrix). You can fix that with a call to `zip`:

```
res_tr = zip(*res)
R, P, T, L, D, E, Obj = res_tr
```

Edit: Shortest of all, you can avoid building the intermediate list with a generator expression passed directly to `zip()`:

```
R, P, T, L, D, E, Obj = zip(*(list(foo.cvxEDA(edaN, 1./fs, tenum, 0.7, 10.0, 0.0008, 0.01)) for tenum in tau))
```

One final note: In all of these, you can replace "`for i, tenum in enumerate(tau)`" with "`for tenum in tau`" since you don't seem to be using `i`.

Comment: Thank you so much. A very clear answer! The `i` was the remainder of some earlier attempts of iterating through the numpy array. Thanks for pointing that out also.

Comment: Btw. your last suggestion did not work. It returned a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'tuple'`, which was thrown by the cvxEDA function.

Comment: Are you sure that you removed `enumerate` as well as removing "`i, `"? Because if not, each `tenum` would be set to something like `(0, first_tenum)`, `(1, second_tenum)` etc

Comment: Forgot the enumerate. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
tau = np.arange(2,4.01,0.1)
results = [[] for _ in range(7)]
for i, tenum in enumerate(tau):
    data = foo.cvxEDA(edaN, 1./fs, tenum, 0.7, 10.0, 0.0008, 0.01)
    for r,d in zip(results, data):
        r.append(d)
r, p, t, l, d, e, _obj = results
```

Comment: In the second for-loop you use `r` as index and `d` as placeholder, but `r` and `d` are also the target variables. Is that intentionally? What happens in that loop actually?

Comment: @RobinKramer just a variable names, you can use any other names, sorry for name collision here.